# Is there a way to position the mouse at a certain point with the press of a button?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, mouse

As a healer with mouseover-macros I sometimes lose track of where my mouse is on-screen, losing a few seconds finding it again.

I would like to have a key bound to resetting the mouse position to a point that I can choose (I would want it to jump on the Tank in my UI).

Is there any way to do that?

I would prefer an ingame command solution to an add-on to a windows solution to a third party solution.

Comment: That would be against the rules. Blizzard would count that as a bot i think.

Answer (score 4):

The plain answer is **no**.

Yes, there are a few technical tricks to do this using Windows tools (Power Shell scripts for example), but there is no ingame feature for this for a reason. Anything that positions or moves the mouse automatically is prohibited by Blizzard.

You can use a Windows feature to *find* your cursor more easily, though.

`Control Panel -> Mouse -> see below`

By enabling this setting you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and it will point out where the curser currently is.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I remember that ping function, but with all the special effects flying around I doubt it would help much, but I'll try. Maybe I'll rather make a macro to cast my quick heal on the tank for when I lose sight of my mouse.

Comment: @iraserd that sounds good. I usually have an emergency macro on my healers to heal up my focus target, which is usually the primary tank. Also it might be a good idea to enable some sort of mouse trails addon. I've seen those around and they don't look as crappy as the Windows one.